# How to set the background of a dialog transparent

Tags: android, dialog

how can I set the background in a dialog (which is in the image green) the same as on the side. So that it is grey and transparent?

[image]

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >

   [....]

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code to show dialog

Answer (score 0):

Use the following style to your Dialog, if you are using Dialog fragment

The color is

```
 <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>

 <style name="DialogTransparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
   </style>
```

Add the style to the fragment in manifest

```
<activity android:name=".components.popup.PopUpActivity"
            android:theme="@style/DialogTransparent" />
```